# How to register a xul window as listener of another?

Tags: xul, keylistener

I have a keylistener that receives a function and calls it when a key is pressed:

```
function addKeyListener(functionToCall) {
    addKeyEvent("keypress", function() { functionToCall(arguments[0]) }, false);
}
```

What can I pass to that function to let my window be a keylistener?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your code snippet is trying to achieve, but if you have a reference to another window, and you want to listen to key events on that window, simply use `otherWindow.addEventListener("keypress", eventHandler, false);`.

Comment: I have a working system that uses the above function. I would like my window to use that same function, but I don't know what function is called in a window when a key is pressed.

Comment: Maybe I could pass a function that gets the key event and generate a keypress in my window using that event..

Comment: The reason why I can't add a eventHandler listener as you suggested is becouse I'm not treating the key events. I'm just letting the component do the default treatment for the keys. I just need to notify my window that a key was pressed (in the other window) and it needs to treat it as if it was pressed on the main window.

Comment: Ah, so what you want to do is to dispatch a copy of your key event on the focused element in another window, as if the key was intended for it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so given your clarification, it looks as if you need to do the following:

1. Locate the focused document in the other window: `otherWindow.document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.document`
2. Create a key event: `otherDocument.createEvent('KeyEvents')`
3. Initialise the event (type, code, modifiers etc.) from your key event
4. Locate the focused element, if any, in the other window:
   `otherWindow.document.commandDispatcher.focusedElement`
5. Dispatch the event to the focused element, or document if no element has focus.